# Regex for matching of anchor negation and string

Tags: regex, anchor, matching, word-boundary

I'm trying add a space before a particular string (`Token` for example) by replacing a regex with another: `somethingToken` should become `something Token` but `something Token` should stay 
`something Token_`
and not
`something  Token` (with 2 spaces)

I'm having trouble finding a regex that would match a non-space character and then the Token but without including the non-space character in the match (otherwise it would get replaced as well). 
A (failed) attempt was to try to negate a `\b` anchor (which should match the beginning of a word), but I don't know if I can negate an anchor. 
Any help on this is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java but it should really be as language agnostic as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just found the answer to this, perhaps it will be useful for someone else:

```
\BToken
```

which represents a negated word boundary, so essentially matching wherever the standard word boundary (\b) does not match. For my example, it does indeed match *somethingToken* but not *something Token* which is left as is.

Comment: So how did you decide to make (token) atomic? (For future readers).   Obviously you don't want to replace the whole token, right?

Comment: In my case, I had no need to make sure Token is atomic (I am sure it was, based on the kind of text I am working with). But if you need to make sure for a more general-purpose utility method, you can use another word boundary (not a negated one this time) - \b. As for the replacement, yes, I did want to replace the "Token" with " Token "

Answer (score 1):

In Java, this can be achieved as follows:

```
final String text = "fooToken foo Token";

// Prints 'foo Token foo Token'
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(?<=\\S)(?=Token)", " "));
```

The concepts here are lookbehind and lookahead. See [Regex Tutorial - Lookahead and Lookbehind zero-width assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`(?<!\u0020)(?=Token)`

This will look behind for a non-space, then will lookahead for Token, but have no width.  This way you can replace this match with a space.

Edit: If you need it to work in Javascript,
`\u0020?(?=Token)`
Make a space optional, then you will replace the space with a space for no net change.

Comment: Negative lookbehind syntax is `(?<!pattern)`. `(?!pattern)` is a negative lookahead.